# start a new line &#xA; doesn't work with SAX parser

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I tried both DOM and SAX parser and I want to read something like this from a large XML file:

```
<qbody>What kind of environment that SQLite can run on? &#xA;A. Android only &#xA;B. Windows &#xA;C. Windows and Mac &#xA;D. Windows, Mac and Linux &#xA;E. All of above and many more</qbody>
```

DOM parser recognises the 
 and makes a new line while SAX just ignore all the string before 
 and just gives E. All of above and many more as output. So my question is how can I make a new line syntax so that it works well with SAX. For more info, I use this parser for an Android app and read local xml file. Thanks for your helps

Comment: Are you using some pre-defined parser or did you write your own? Post the code if you wrote it yourself, or a link to what you used if not.

Comment: I use pre-defined parser, example from this site: http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/code/SAXParserExample.java

Comment: I found the answer myself, this is a problem with UTF-8 XML file. How to deal with it can be found here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-utf-8-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/